# How does an atom get rid of electrons?

Tags: electrons

I know that if an atom has 4 electrons in its outer shell it will share 4 with other atoms to have a full valence shell. But what if the atom only has 3? I understand that it will likely get rid of three instead of picking up 5 more to share, but how does it get rid of the three? 
Thank you

Comment: You might wanna study some things about bonds.

Answer (score 1):

Atoms with one outer electron (e.g. sodium), called alkali metals, or two outer electrons (e.g. calcium, strontium), called alkaline earths, and even the aluminum-scandium metals are not good at sharing -- they tend to lose their outer electrons given the opportunity, e.g. when a halogen is near. These form *ionic* compounds, such as table salt, in which case the Na+ has given up one electron, which stays close to the Cl- ion.

Elements in columns closer together don't get away with outright theft, and share their outer electrons more equitably in a covalent bond.

That said, it's an oversimplification, in that a bond is not necessarily fully ionic or fully covalent and may fall somewhere in between. See https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OY2_q-1t2Q8 for a video on this.